# How can I compile a library in 32bit on a 64bit Mac machine (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, build, makefile, osx-mountain-lion, 32-bit

I want to compile tesseract http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ in 32bit on my Macbook. But I have a 64bit Mac OS Mountain Lion machine.

There is a Makefile, and I tried:

(1) $ ./configure --with-arch=i386
(2) $ $./configure --build=i386-apple-darwin --host=i386-apple-darwin --target=i386-apple-darwin

Both didn't work. The library compiled is still 64bit. Actually for (2) I see, after running the ./configure, it says somethings like "checking for i386-apple-darwin-g++ .. no", actually everything it checked for i386 had a "no" in the end. But the compilation succeed, just the library does not seem to be 32bit.

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Have to tried setting `CXX=clang++; CXXFLAGS="-arch 386" ./configure ...`?

Comment: Do you mean I should do "./configure CXX=clang++; CXXFLAGS="-arch 386""???? I did it, and yes, I got the lib sucessfully compiled, then I try to use it in openframeworks (32bit), still get the following ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Sorry I'm confused.  Did my suggestion allow it to compile?

Comment: Yes, I just copied "./configure CXX=clang++; CXXFLAGS="-arch 386" " to my Terminal, and after that i ran "make". It compiled, but the compiled library still does not seemed to be a usable i386 library.

Comment: Have you confirmed that using `file /path/to/lib.a`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the -m32 to specify building 32-bit executables in the CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS. However, the MacOSX sdks for 10.7 and 10.8 don't have 32-bit i386 code to link against (only MacOSX10.6.sdk). I recommend using macports to install/build the tesseract engine on Mac OS X 10.7+.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong about the 10.7 and 10.8 SDKs not having 32-bit i386 code.  You may be thinking about PowerPC support.